# Reset algorithm counter

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering

I am writing an algorithm, where the **Input** has two lines. I first tried with `itemize` environment, later substitued with `algorithmic` for uniform look-and-feel. The problem is, the counter in the actual algorithm now starts with 3. To solve, I put it within another `algorithmic` (those lines are marked with `% Comment out this line`). This solves the numbering issues, but adds the issue of indentation (now it looks likes those are the lines under **Output**).

I have this minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}%
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}%


\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Caption}\label{label}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Input 
            {\begin{algorithmic}[1]
                    \item Something in line 1
                    \item Something in line 2
                \end{algorithmic}
            }
            \Output {Suppose something is in here}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1] % Comment out this line 
                \State Here goes the actual algorithm
                \State Now the next step
                \State This step, and we are done
                \State \Return {Here you go}
            \end{algorithmic} % Comment out this line 
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Questions (all about indentation):

1. Notice the lines within **Input** do not have equal indentation (line 2 is shifted to the left a bit more). How can I fix that?
2. How can I reduce the indentation the steps in the actual algorithm given the current version?
3. (Alternate to 2, getting an answer to at least one would suffice). The indentation in question 2 goes away if the marked lines are commented out. In this case, how can I reset the algorithm number back to 1?

Comment: Is the following closer to the expected output or do you want to keep the two "Input" lines numbered? https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5LXA.png

Comment: @leandriis That will work. Line numbering inside **Input** is not essential (but desirable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two suggestions. Probably one of them suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}%
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}%


\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Caption}\label{label}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Input Something in line 1
                     
                   Something in line 2 
            \Output {Suppose something is in here}
                \State Here goes the actual algorithm
                \State Now the next step
                \State This step, and we are done
                \State \Return {Here you go} 
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Caption}\label{label}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Input 
            \item Something in line 1 
            \item  Something in line 2 \setcounter{ALG@line}{0}
            \Output {Suppose something is in here}
                \State Here goes the actual algorithm
                \State Now the next step
                \State This step, and we are done
                \State \Return {Here you go} 
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    
\end{document}
```