# Formatting a Pseudocode using Algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e, pseudocode

I'm trying to format a pseudocode using the Algorithm2e package. The desired output has the following format:
[image]
Here's the code I've tried to format this pseudocode:

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\SetKwInOut{Parameters}{Parameters}
\SetKwInOut{Procedure}{Procedure}

\textbf{Input:} \\
\qquad$\bullet$ An Oracle operator effecting the transformation $\ket{x}\ket{q}\rightarrow\ket{x}\ket{q\oplus f(x)}$\\
\textbf{Output:}\\
\qquad$\bullet$ The unique bit string x satisfying Eq. (32)\\
\textbf{Procedure:}\\
\qquad$\bullet$\ \textbf{Step 1:} Perform state initialization\\
\qquad$\bullet$\ \textbf{Step 2:} Apply Grover operator
\caption{Grover's Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
```

And the output looks like:
[image]

I wonder if there's a way I can make the text/equations do not 'exceed' the `bullet` point as a new line begins. Thanks！

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599142/reset-algorithm-counter/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset algorithm counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599142/reset-algorithm-counter)

Comment: @hola -- The question you cite doesn't deal with line wrap; none of the lines in the example requires more than one line.  The problem here is that the page doesn't appear to be wide enough, which is why everything doesn't fit on one line.  To find out what the allowable line length really is, it's necessary to know what document class is being used.

Answer (score 1):

use `enumerate`:

```
\begin{itemize}\setlength\itemsep{.5em}
\item[\textbf{Input:}]
\item An Oracle operator effecting the transformation $ \left| x\right\rangle\left| q\right\rangle\rightarrow\left| x\right\rangle\left| q\oplus f(x)\right\rangle$.
\item[\textbf{Output:}]
\item The unique bit string x satisfying Eq. (32)
\item[\textbf{Procedure:}]
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}\setlength\itemsep{-.2em}\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries Step \arabic{enumi}:}
\item Perform state initialization
\item Apply Grover operator
\item ??
\item profit
\end{enumerate}
```

[image: list]